# CAML Query to Return all rows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, caml

I am having Sql Query like

```
// sTitle is my input string
 string sTitle='something';
 Select Title From EmployeeList WHERE Title like '%sTitle%' or 0=sTitle OrderBy Title Desc;
```

How do i Build it in CAML Query? 
In CAML Query we can match with the fieldNames but i need to **compare with** integer or some **constant** with my **InputString**

And one more thing How do i achieve the **Descending** concept in **CAML query**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample CAML Query:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='Title' />
         <Value Type='Text'>1234</Value>
      </Contains>
   </Where>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='False' />
   </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

In CAML `Like` may be done using `Conatins`. Moreover, `OrderBy` is used for sorting. I would suggest you to use [CAML Query builder](https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/). It will help you understand the concepts of CAML.

Comment: I need to compare my input string with some constant as we compare in sql ... Is it possible?

Comment: CAML Query compares the field values of a list item. So if your constant is stored in some field, you can compare the input string with that.

Comment: ya i understand that.. but something we are querying in sql, sameway I am trying to acheive it on sharepoint... So for implementing my case what would be ur advise?

Comment: @Sarath, you can upvote or mark the reply as answer if it helped resolve your issue. Same is true for teylyn's answer.

Comment: For Vote I need 15 points.. And ur answers are satisfied half of t content oly..

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate the CAML query is to start with a SharePoint list view.

If you can use the view dialog to define the filter and the sort, then you can grab the corresponding CAML with SharePoint Designer.

In this case, you may want to create a view on the EmployeeList. Filter by Title with "contains" and the desired string.

Use the Sort section to sort descending by the desire value.

Once the view shows the correct results, open the page with SharePoint Designer, select the web part and in code view look for the Query tag near the top of the web part definition. That's your CAML query.

You can also pass filter parameters into the query with either a filter web part or a URL parameter. If you need details for that, pipe up.

Comment: little info. But I need to compare my input string with some constant as we compare in sql ... Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Pass in the constant as a URL parameter. Create a parameter in the XSLTListViewWebPart that reads the URL parameter. Then filter the list by the parameter.

Comment: ya.. For Descending, Is there any way in camel queries?

Comment: Yes. Look at the "OrderBy" in a CAML query, like the one posted by @Nadeem. Can you see where it says `Ascending='FALSE'` -- Can you interpret what that might mean?